# Unfairness of TCP with in large RTT context

Tags: wireless, tcp

Versions of TCP that use Van Jacobson algorithm are unfair in some contexts, such as satellite communication. I cannot understand why. Is this problem caused by asymmetric links, in which the receiver has more possibility to send acknowledgement packets than the sender?

Comment: Hint: Google Bandwidth-Delay Product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, TCP's Congestion Window (CW) grows as new ACK packets arrive.

Then, if a connection C1 has a large RTT it means that *fewer* ACKs will arrive in a certain time period compared to another connection C2 with a smaller RTT, due to the following facts:

- the destination will send an acknowledgement when the packet arrives, so in C2 this happens **earlier** than in C1
- the C2 acknowledgement itself will take a shorter time period to reach the source

Answer (score 0):

After some researches I have found an answer. It is not only for the delay-bandwidth product as suggested in the comment but for some reasons:

- The throughput of a sender could be written as Throughput=CongestionWindow/RoundTripTime, so if you have a bigger RTT you need bigger CW to reach the same throughput;
- The capacity of the channel could be written as Capacity=Delay*Bandwidth, so you could retrieve the bandwidth available in this way Bandwidth=Capacity/Delay (and Delay could be the half of the RTT or equal the RTT considering that for each packet the ACK is needed);
- The CongestionWindow could be written as function of the RTT in that way:
      - CongestionWindow = 2 ^ (t/RTT) in slow start phase, where t is the time;
       - CongestionWindow = ss + (t - tss)/RTT in congestion avoidance phase, where ss is the slow start threshold, t is the time, tss is the time when you reach the slow start threshold and ss is the value of the slow start threshold.
  Avoiding to make formulas more complicate because of the possible error that can occur that change the CongestionWindow and th slow start threshold,
  it could be easly seen that the CongestionWindow strongly depends on the RTT, and since it appears on the denominator both in slow start phase and in congestion avoidance phase, bigger the RTT is, more disadvantaged the sender is.